# Valor seleccionado por defecto en combo box dinámico Power BI

Tags: combobox, dropdownlist, powerbi, microsoft

Sucede que se tiene un selectbox o dropdown en un dashboard de Power BI que muestra todos los meses de todos los años en orden decreciente, tal y como se muestra en la siguiente imagen.

[image: imagen01]

Entonces necesito que por defecto se quede seleccionado el primer valor del combo que en este caso sería el último mes, pero mes a mes el primer valor del combo va cambiando debido a que el orden de los meses es decreciente y muestra todos los meses de todos los años.

Ahora bien, ¿cómo hago para que el valor por defecto siempre sea el último es (el primer valor del combo)? El asunto es que si actualmente dejo "Octubre, 2019" seleccionado por defecto entonces cuando exista "Noviembre, 2019" o "Diciembre, 2019", etc. seguirá estando seleccionado "Octubre, 2019" y eso no es lo deseable.

¡Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Tienes que hacerlo mediante una measure utilizando DAX para que seleccione el último mes de tu tabla. Aquí te dejo un link que te puede ayudar https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerBI/comments/8vta4f/how_to_set_a_default_slicer_value/

Answer (score 1):

Yo sigo utilizando una técnica basada en una columna en la tabla de calendario donde dice si es el mes actual o anterior al actual. Pongo un filtro por defecto indicando que es el mes actual.

Lo puedes simplificar pero la estrategia es la siguiente
Creamos una medida con la diferencia de meses entre la fecha actual (máxima) y cada mes del calendario.

```
Meses de diferencia = ((12 * YEAR([Fecha])) + MONTH([Fecha]))
```

- ((12 * YEAR(max(Venta[Fecha])) + MONTH(max(Venta[Fecha]))))

Creamos otra medida que nos indicará si el mes seleccionado es el actual

```
Mes relativo = IF([Meses de diferencia]=0
; "Mes actual"
; "Meses anteriores")
```

[image: Ponemos algún elemento gráfico a modo de filtro para que el usuario seleccione]